# Marlin if else goto commands

Tags: button, macros, ninja, g-code

I'm using marlin & gcode macros m810-m819 assigned to 2 external buttons. There is 7 positions X & Y that I want to control via the 2 buttons. I have assigned each of the 7 positions to a macro and can run the macro on its own by pressing the button. I want to assign 2 other macros that decide on the last position that I will link to the buttons e.g

IF M810 GOTO M811|IF M811 GOTO M812|IF M812 GOTO M813 and so on.

When I press the button the display selects the macro but doesn't run it, do you know the correct way of using IF & GOTO in Marlin or is there another way?

Expecting the Gcode Macro to run using IF & GOTO